# Randomize/shuffle cards in stack with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I am building a very simple memory game for a small project. The logic is as follows:

1. click on the input field to choose with how many pairs would you like to play
2. create divs with classes card1, card2 etc.
3. clone divs and randomize their place in the array

Here is my script (fork in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/007y4rju/2/)):

```
$(".button").click(function () {        
    // get the value from the input
    var numCards = parseInt($('input').val());

    for (var i = 1; i <= numCards; i++) {
        // create the cards
        $(".container").append("<div class='card" + i + " cards'></div>") &&
        $(".card" + i).clone().appendTo(".container");
    }

    // randomize cards in stack
    var cards = $(".cards");
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
        var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
        var target3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
        cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2)).before(cards.eq(target3));
    }
});
```

what I need now is to adjust the 3rd step, meaning to dynamically create the target vars, and the last line of the code

```
cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2)).before(cards.eq(target3));
```

So please make me a suggestion - how would you do it? And bare in mind this is a project for beginners. Thank you!

Comment: Why not to randomize index in a class name (`card%i%`) when creating divs? Then you don't need to shuffle DOM elements.

Comment: i sugest you put all the cards in a array and than shuffle them

Comment: would like to try that, please add your answer and explain it a bit more and add the updated script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".button").click(function () {        
    // get the value from the input
    var numCards = parseInt($('input').val());

    for (var i = 1; i <= numCards; i++) {
        // create the cards
        $(".container").append("<div class='card" + i + " cards'></div>") &&
        $(".card" + i).clone().appendTo(".container");
    }

    var parent = $(".container");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

see jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/007y4rju/8/

source: http://jsfiddle.net/C6LPY/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version of the code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/007y4rju/6/

Please, check if the behavior is consistent with the original code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".button").click(function () {        
        // get the value from the input
        var numCards = parseInt($('input').val());

        for (var i = 1; i <= numCards; i++) {
            // create the cards
            $(".container").append("<div class='card" + i + " cards'></div>") &&
            $(".card" + i).clone().appendTo(".container");
        }

        // randomize cards in stack
        var cards = $(".cards");
        var startTarget = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
        var collection = cards.eq(startTarget);
        var nextTarget;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            nextTarget = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
            collection.before(cards.eq(nextTarget));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can randomize index in a class name (`card%i%`) when cloning divs. Then you don't need to shuffle cloned divs; you can append them as is.

```
$(".button").click(function () {        
    // get the value from the input
    var numCards = parseInt($('input').val());

    for (var i = 1; i <= numCards; i++) {
        // create the cards
        $(".container").append("<div class='card" + i + " cards'></div>");
    }

    var aIndices = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= numCards; i++) {
        var ix;
        do ix = Math.round(Math.random() * (numCards - 1)) + 1;
        while (aIndices.indexOf(ix) >= 0);
        aIndices.push(ix);
        // clone
        $(".card" + ix).clone().appendTo(".container");
    }
});
```

Comment: something is wrong with the loop, it breaks the chrome tab

Comment: @pres Which the loop?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/007y4rju/11/ when you input a value it breaks. I figured - it's a loop problem. I don't know where.